# Run CGSession -switchToUserID on remote Mac

Tags: authentication, session, applescript, osascript, switch-user

I have next script on my remote Mac:

```
on run
    do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID 502"
    delay 5
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "mypassword" & return
        delay 4
        keystroke tab
        keystroke return
    end tell

end run
```

This script works fine if I run it when I login through VNC (in cmd `osascript <script name>`), BUT it doesn't work when I run it through ssh. I noticed that only `do shell script "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID 502"` is my problem, another lines work through ssh.

So, I can't use CGSession through ssh on remote Mac?